# std:map iterator returns badptr on find

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2008

I have my `std::map` defined as

```
typedef std::map<string,ImageData*> ImageDataMap;
typedef std::pair<string,ImageData*> ImageDataPair;
typedef std::map<string,ImageData*>::iterator ImageDataIterator;
```

The above map stores string which is an image file name and `ImageData` which is the the image metadata. When i use the find as shown below

```
ImageDataIterator iter =  imageMap->find("Fader.tga");
if(iter == imageMap->end()){...}
```

The `iter->first` is a badptr and so it fails the if condition below is. What's wrong here? Running on vc9 express edition on xp64 (the program is 32bit)

Comment: This is not enough code to reproduce the error you get.

Comment: If I'have understood correctly you check iter->first inside the if clause? If it is the case, it means that your string was not found. That is why the iter first is the badptr.

Comment: You need to review all the answers and accept the one that helped you solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An iterator returned as `map::end` by `map::find()` means that the specified key was not found in the container. You cannot dereference it to access its elements. It will crash your application.

**EDIT:**

Let's be clear. The problem is that you are inverting the logic, ok? You can only use an iterator if it's valid, therefore `iter` must be different from `map::end`. This means that `map::find()` was successful and found the element you were looking for:

```
if (iter != imageMap->end())
{
  // element FOUND! Use it!
  cout << iter->first << endl;
}
else
{
  // Not found! Can't use it.
}
```

Your mistake is the *if* comparison you're currently doing: `if (iter == imageMap->end())` which means *execute the following block of code if the element I searched for is not in the map*. That's why when `iter->first` is executed the application breaks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

typedef int ImageData;
typedef std::map<std::string,ImageData*> ImageDataMap;
typedef std::map<std::string,ImageData*>::iterator ImageDataIterator;


using namespace std;


int main()
{
  ImageDataMap mymap;

  int value_1 = 10;
  int value_2 = 20;
  int value_3 = 30;

  mymap["a"] = &value_1;
  mymap["b"] = &value_2;
  mymap["c"] = &value_3;

  // Search/print valid element
  ImageDataIterator it = mymap.find("a");
  if (it != mymap.end()) // will execute the block if it finds "a"
  {          
      cout << it->first << " ==> " << *(it->second) << endl;
  }

  // Searching for invalid element
  it = mymap.find("d"); // // will only execute the block if it doesn't find "d"
  if (it == mymap.end())
  {
    cout << "!!! Not found !!!" << endl;
    cout << "This statement will crash the app" << it->first << endl;;
  }

  cout << "Bye bye" << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: well the problem is if(iter == imageMap->end()) doesn't work. It doesn't check for the end condition if the key is not found. The spc, says it is supposed to return end of the map, but it doesnt.

Answer (score 0):

Perhapes you should change `if(iter == imageMap->end()){...}` to `if(iter != imageMap->end()){...}`

Comment: well i need to check if the image was not found so if i do if(iter == imageMap->end()) or if( !(iter != imageMap->end()) ) makes no diff